# I'm getting 503 error when I try to connect to my new environment

Tags: apache2, digital-ocean, http-status-code-503

I already have 2 environments setup and working, I was trying to create a third one similar to the ones already created. But for the backend I'm getting errors related to the proxy I think.

This is the error log:

```
[proxy:error] [pid 2814] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: HTTP: attempt to connect to 178.62.203.15:8990 (testing.api.requests.tarbeeta.com) failed
[proxy:error] [pid 2814] AH00959: ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (testing.api.requests.tarbeeta.com) for 60s
[proxy_http:error] [pid 2814] [client 41.44.42.14:64296] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: testing.api.requests.tarbeeta.com, referer: http://testing.api.r$
```

This is the setup of my vhost

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin admin@tarbeeta.com
        ServerName testing.api.requests.tarbeeta.com
        ServerAlias testing.api.requests.tarbeeta.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/testing.requests.tarbeeta.com/server/public_html
        ProxyPass / http://testing.api.requests.tarbeeta.com:8990/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://testing.api.requests.tarbeeta.com:8990/

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =testing.api.requests.tarbeeta.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

This is the same configuration as the other two vhosts, they use different ports though. I don't know if I have to configure the port somewhere else to have this work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The error shows a connection attempt at port `8990`, but your Apache config is listening to port `80`. You will want to adjust Apache to look at the correct port with your virtual hosts as well as in `/etc/apache2/ports.conf`. From there, if you are using `ufw` on Ubuntu with your Droplet, you'll need to update the firewall to allow traffic on port `8990` through.

#### For your Virtual Host

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

Becomes:

```
<VirtualHost *:8990>
```

#### For ports.conf

```
# If you just change the port or add more ports here, you will likely also
# have to change the VirtualHost statement in
# /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

Listen 80

<IfModule ssl_module>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Becomes:

```
# If you just change the port or add more ports here, you will likely also
# have to change the VirtualHost statement in
# /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

Listen 80
Listen 8990

<IfModule ssl_module>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

<sub>**Note:** If traffic will never be sent to the server over port `80`, you can remove the line from the file.</sub>

#### Update the Firewall

```
sudo ufw allow 8990
```

#### Finally ...

Restart Apache:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

This will give you what you need.